# Hide out of stock products only in search result pages

Tags: magento, magento-1.7

We can easily hide out of stock products in categories and catalog search through : System > Configuration > Catalog > Inventory > Display Out of Stock Products

Yet, how can we hide products only in search results ?

Answer (score 4):

You could override `_getSearchableProducts` function in class `Mage_CatalogSearch_Model_Resource_Fulltext` so that it always searches in-stock products.

File to modify: `app/code/core/Mage/CatalogSearch/Model/Resource/Fulltext.php`

```
/**
 * Retrieve searchable products per store
 *
 * @param int $storeId
 * @param array $staticFields
 * @param array|int $productIds
 * @param int $lastProductId
 * @param int $limit
 * @return array
 */
protected function _getSearchableProducts($storeId, array $staticFields, $productIds = null, $lastProductId = 0, $limit = 100)
{        
    ...

    ->join(
        array('stock_status' => $this->getTable('cataloginventory/stock_status')),
        $writeAdapter->quoteInto(
            'stock_status.product_id=e.entity_id AND stock_status.stock_status = 1 AND stock_status.website_id=?', // add stock_status = 1 condition
            $websiteId
        ),
        array('in_stock' => 'stock_status')
    );

    ....
}
```

Remember to reindex "Catalog Search Index" afterwards.

Answer (score 1):

The above solution using observer also hides the in category. The question is to hide only in search results. so directly adding instock filter product collection results.phtml is appropriate.

i.e `Mage::getSingleton('cataloginventory/stock')->addInStockFilterToCollection($productCollection);`

correct me if i miss any thing here.

Answer (score 0):

I know a way by which you can achieve this.

Inside Magento/app/design/frontend/rwd/default/template/catalogsearch/result.phtml

```
$this->getProductListHtml() ;
```

gives you the desired search result.

Inside list.phtml check this out.

```
$_productCollection=$this->getLoadedProductCollection();
```

Magento allows you a way by which you can observe the collection add filters before/after the collection is loaded that is called the **Observer way**.

Inside the event you observe, try using following particularly for search results:

```
Mage::getSingleton('cataloginventory/stock')->addInStockFilterToCollection($productCollection);
```

Hope it helps.